# Need an explanation

Tags: python

```
startmsg = "hello"
endmsg = ""
for i in range(0,len(startmsg)):
    endmsg=startmsg[i] + endmsg
print(endmsg)
```

Why is the result: "olleh", a not "hello"?

Comment: Try `endmsg = endmsg + startmsg[i]`.

Comment: why do you think it should be "hello"? [ask]

Comment: Yes, that works. But I don't understand the logic behind this one. How does it concatenate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this code iterates, it adds each letter to the front of what's been iterated over previously. The end result is a reversed string.

As we iterate:

```
endmsg = "h"

endmsg = "eh"

endmsg = "leh"

endmsg = "lleh"

endmsg = "olleh"
```

Iterating over indexes like this is not particularly idiomatic Python. Rather, if the index is not needed, it would be more Pythonic to iterate over the characters directly.

```
startmsg = "hello"
endmsg = ""

for ch in startmsg:
    endmsg = ch + endmsg

print(endmsg)
```

Comment: Got it. I know it was a stupid question but just couldn't get it. Thank you.

Comment: In my experience, most questions feel stupid when you see the answer. :)